# How to retrieve an ID in onContextItemSelected()

Tags: android, contextmenu

I need the ID from an item in `onContextItemSelected()`. I use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.listView1) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Optionen");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, info.position, 0, "Artikel entfernen");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lv.getItemAtPosition(item.getItemId()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

The `info.position` var could not be read from `onContextItemSelected` with `item.getItemId`! The app crashed with the log: *String empty*. Can you find a mistake? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I changed the code to:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.listView1) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Optionen");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, info.position, 0, "delete post");
  }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  //lv.getItemAtPosition(0).toString()


  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();


  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info.position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lv.getItemAtPosition(item.getItemId()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


  return true;
}
```

But also this code doesn't work (NotFoundException). I have a listview (R.id.listView1) with items. If the user clicks on an item long, the context menu appears. There is the option "delete post". Then I need the ID from the post to delete it!

Are there other solutions?

**UPDATE 2**
I solved the problem:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lv.getItemAtPosition(info.position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info.id` will be the `id` value associated with the given item in the `AdapterView`.

To get at `info` in `onContextItemSelected()`, use:

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
```

Also, note that context menus are becoming much less popular, in favor of action modes (a.k.a., contextual action bars) with an action bar.

Comment: I updated the code. But it does not work. Furthermore, I have added some explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @user1756209: "But also this code doesn't work (NotFoundException)" -- you are trying to display a `Toast`, using a string resource with a random ID. That is not going to work. If your objective is to display a `Toast` whose message happens to be an `int`, you will need to convert that `int` to a `String` so that Android does not treat your `int` as a string resource ID. Furthermore, you inquired about "the ID from the post", yet you are examining `info.position`, instead of `info.id` as I pointed out in my answer.